# Delete data from Listview item.how i can delete all data from listview item position from sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-listview

How i can get listview item position and how i can delete these all data.

```
  registerForContextMenu(listview);
```

///

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Cancel");
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

}
```

// I call from contextItemSelelected

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
        //delete method by id from sqlite
    } else if (item.getTitle() == "Cancel") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please Specify the Scenario well , How can you assume which item is deleting without any check or click ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the item at the position you long clicked on list item like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int position = info.position;

        YourObj obj = (YourObj) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        long id = obj.getId();
        //Do what ever you want to do with id here!!!!
}
```